# how to stop animation and sliding subviews while flipleft animation in iphone?

Tags: iphone, animation, subview, flip

i am using following code for navigating from one view to another view in iphone app.

```
-(IBAction)navigateToInfo:(id)sender
{
    InfoDetailViewController *vc=[[InfoDetailViewController alloc]init];
   //[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
   // [vc release];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    for(UIView *view1 in self.view.subviews)
    {
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    }


    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


-(IBAction)navigateToMainScreen:(id)sender
{ 
    MainVC *vc=[[MainVC alloc]init];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
      [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
      self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    for(UIView *view1 in self.view.subviews)
    {
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

But it slides subviews like uinavigation bar button item,button etc also along with the main view.How to prevent subviews from changing their positions
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This solved the issue.


-(IBAction)navigateToInfo:(id)sender
{
    InfoDetailViewController *vc=[[InfoDetailViewController alloc]init];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view.window cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];


}
```